# which GPO will put a certificate in to the localmachine\personal?

Tags: group-policy, certificate

I have a wildcard certificate used mostly for IIS websites. I would like to install the certificate via GPO. Not necessarily change IIS to use the certificate, but at least get it installed in to the LocalMachine\Personal store.

What GPO do I put the certificate in?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Neither GPO setting would install the certificate in Personal certificate store. You have to install it either, manually, or use scripting (for example, PowerShell remoting).

Answer (score -1):

You're probably looking for "Trusted Root Certification Authorities".

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/deployment/distribute-certificates-to-client-computers-by-using-group-policy

Comment: it is incorrect answer.